# Facebook Connect iPhone API logout not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am attempting to write a Facebook integration in an iPhone app I'm working on. I have it logging in just fine, but I don't like the idea of being able to turn a feature on without being able to turn it off. So, in working on the logout functionality, I have been caught in a snag.

```
- (IBAction) logoutClicked:(id)sender {
    if (fbLoggedIn)
    {
        FBSession * mySession = [FBSession session];

        [mySession logout];
    }
}

- (void)sessionDidLogout:(FBSession*)session
{
    NSLog(@"Session logged out.");
    [theLoginButton setTitle:@"Facebook Time!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    fbLoggedIn = FALSE;
    theLogoutButton.enabled = NO;
    theLogoutButton.alpha = 0;
}
```

The logoutClicked method responds to a button in my xib. The delegate method is not getting called. I have tried setting the Facebook session as a property in my ViewController in order to store/access the data across methods, but that didn't seem to work either. Anybody have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Is the sessionDidLogout implemented in a class which implements FBSessionDelegate? 
And is it an instance of that class that you passed as a delegate when creating the session with the method [FBSession sessionForApplication:@"XXX" secret:@"YYY" delegate:(DELEGATE)] ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code for logout. I got this from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6068337/763747).

```
- (void) fbDidLogout {
    NSLog(@"Log out");
    // Remove saved authorization information if it exists
    if ([userDefaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]) {
        [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
(void)logout {

//self.sessionDelegate = delegate;

appDelegate.facebook.accessToken = nil;
appDelegate.facebook.expirationDate  = nil;

NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];

for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}


NSLog(@"Log out");
// Remove saved authorization information if it exists
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([userDefaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]) {
    [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}

}
```