# Calling logout function of facebook ios sdk is not clearing user Credentials

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, logout

While implementing facebook SSO, calling logout function of facebook ios sdk is not clearing user Credentials and it does not ask to login next time.

Comment: are you refering to OAuth and the external mobile safari opening?

Comment: yes, which is given in developer.facebook.com

Answer (score 9):

I Used Graph Api.....

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSString *client_id = @"dsfgdgfgfgdfgvdfg";

    //alloc and initalize our FbGraph instance
    self.fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];

    //begin the authentication process.....
    [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) 
                         andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];
}


- (void)logOutButtonPressed {

    NSLog(@"logout");

    fbGraph.accessToken = nil;
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }

    [self loginButtonPressed:nil];
}
```

And This code is WORKING FINE..TRY THIS

Comment: @Pallavi does this really remove the cookie in mobile safari? I've seen this code before and debugged a bit but to no avail.

Comment: I am not using mobile safari ,, login is web view and I give button for logout.

Comment: @Pallavi I think that this works, however if you use one of the Facebook libs it'll launch mobile safari which is a more trustgaining way to let the user login: The app does not have access to the credentials, in a webView you could access those.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) I used this

Comment: This works when i logout and then again tap the button for login but this doesn't when i quit the app after logout and again open the app and tap on login button.This driving me crazy from a while.

Comment: If I log out and quit app then this will show login page on starting app

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same, however I think it's not a bug, confusing though.

Facebook places a cookie in the mobile safari which refers to a valid session or maybe an access token. If you logout with the Facebook lib it clears the access token and all cookies of the webview used not in mobile safari. Actually you can't do that by code. Now if you come back and mobile safari opens up, there is still a valid session and you are logged in again without entering credentials.

You may file a bug to ask if Facebook can invalidate the access token server side.