# objective c Facebook Logout

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I'm developing an api that can post photo on facebook. When you click post: if you re not logged in it shows log in dialog, you log in and post is successful. if you re logged in it simply posts the stuff.

I've created a button that implements the logout logic  like this [facebook logout:self];. the button works fine.

So the problem is... When I click logoutButton it calls the logout method but somehow keeps credentials and if I press postButton again it wouldn't ask me to enter my credentials . Only after I restart my application and press postButton it show the login dialog.

As I understand it should delete or clean some credential or cache to allow me to reenter username and password, but it don't.

Here is Log out method, I call it from button.

```
- (void) FBLogout {


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"access_token"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"exp_date"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

if (facebook==nil) {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"IN Logout");
    [facebook logout:self];
    [facebook retain];
}
```

}

I've dug a lot but get nothing.

Help please. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6068337/1114171)

Comment: Solved... 2 days and nights...but solved... the reason was not the logout logic, there was a problem with isLoggedIn Boolean..